# Vue nested route not rendered

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a nested route that is not rendering and throws an error:

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:571 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <BlEditOrder>
       <BlOrders> at src\components\orders\Orders.vue
         <VContent>
           <VApp>
             <App> at src\App.vue
               <Root>
```

**Routes:**

```
{
      path: '/orders',
      name: 'orders',
      component: Orders,
      beforeEnter: Auth,
      children: [
        { path: '', component: OrdersList },
        {
          path: 'new',
          name: 'newOrder',
          component: NewOrder
        },
        {
          path: ':id',
          name: 'editOrder',
          component: EditOrder,
          props: true
        }
      ]
    }
```

**EditOrder.vue:**

```
<template>
<h1>Edit Order</h1>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'blEditOrder',
  props: ['id'],
  data: function() {
    return {
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log('this.id', this.id);
  }
}

</script>
```

**Orders.vue**

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'blOrders',
  data: function() {    
    return {}
  },
  methods: {}
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

`OrdersList` is rendering just fine, but when i go to `order/new` or `orders/1234` i get the above mentioned error.

I do see the log statement, it logs 1234.

I have no idea what's wrong :(

Comment: In your routes, are you importing `EditOrder` with `require()` or `import`?

Comment: @DecadeMoon with import

Comment: Can you make live demo of this? If it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it, the problem was that i extracted the scripts to a different file:

```
<script src="./new">
</script>
```

and since my vue file is called `New.vue`, and my js is called `new.js`, webpack got confused and didn't import them correctly.